# My hdd does not show when I connect it to my laptop or any other system. How to mount my hard drive without formatting it in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, hard-disk

I have an important data in my 2TB external HDD. While I was transferring data into HDD, it suddenly showed error in copying. The HDD is still showing in the list of all disks in my laptop but does not mount it in the system. How to resolve this problem without losing my data.

Comment: you need another 2TB hard disk so you can make a raw dump with gddrescue

Comment: What method is being used for the transfer (software)? Note:- Formatting is not a method of mounting, it is a way of losing data.

Comment: There are utilities such as `fsck` which can try to fix corruption. **But copy your disk first and `fsck` the copy.** If you're worried about losing data never try to fix in place because fixing the corruption could completely destroy the data.